# How to set SelectedValue of a Combo binded to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, combobox

I wanna bind a dictionary to a combobox.
My code is this (here I simplified it a little)

```
public class MyObject
{
  private AnotherObject _obj;

  public MyObject() { }

  public MyObject(AnotherObject obj)
  {
    _obj = obj;
  }

  public string ObjType
  {
    get { return (_obj != null ? _obj.GetType() : "NO OBJECT" ); }
  }

  public string ObjString
  {
    get { return (_obj != null ? _obj.ToString() : "NO OBJECT" ); }
  }

}


public class MyClass 
{    
  private Dictionary<string, MyObject> _BindingButtons;

  public MyClass() 
  {
    _BindingButtons["KEY_1"] = new MyObject( CreateAnotherObject() );
    _BindingButtons["KEY_2"] = new MyObject( CreateAnotherObject() );
    ...
    ...
  }

  public Dictionary<string, MyObject> BindingButtons
  {
    get { return _BindingButtons; }      
  }    

}
```

Now, in the xaml I wrote

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding BindingButtons}"
          DisplayMemberPath="ObjString"
          SelectedValuePath="KEY_1"
          SelectedValue="{Binding ???? }"/>
```

and I have two problem

- the combo list is empty (the dictionary is not empty)
- Is there a way to bind the SelectedValue to something like:

  **"{Binding BindingButtons[KEY_1]}"**

  without create a property for each combo?

Where I wrong?
Regards.

**[EDIT]**

regarding my question on SelectedValue...

Suppose to have 10 combos with the same ItemsSource. Now, instead of write 10 properties (one for each combo), is there a way to write something like that (to handle SelectedItem):

```
class Test
{
  private string[] _Items = new string[10];

  public string GetItem(int index)
  {
    return _Items[index];
  }

  public void SetItem(int index, string value)
  {
    _Items[index] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: better create a List of KeyValuePair and bind it !

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, can you provide a minimal example to put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary has a collection property `Values` which you can leverage here

according to your data model this should work

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding BindingButtons.Values}"
          DisplayMemberPath="ObjString"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemInVM}"/>
```

I was not sure about the purpose of SelectedValue in your question, I replaced it with SelectedItem in example, you may adjust according to your needs.

**EDIT**

answer for your edit

you have two options to bind the individual combobox to an array

but before that you need to convert the array field to a public property and initialize accordingly, otherwise binding may fail

```
public string[] Items { get; set; }
```

and then bind using indexers `Items[0]` etc.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding BindingButtons.Values}"
          DisplayMemberPath="ObjString"
          SelectedValuePath="ObjType"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Items[0]}"/>
```

or create the array of `MyObject` type

```
public MyObject[] Items { get; set; }
```

and binding remain same but using `SelectedItem` property instead of `SelectedValue`

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding BindingButtons.Values}"
          DisplayMemberPath="ObjString"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Items[0]}"/>
```

make sure to initialize your array in constructor `Items = new string[10];` or `Items = new MyObject[10];` 10 is number of combo you have

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited my question to explain better what I mean for SeletedValue/SelectedItem